# fetching current channels disocrd.js-selfbot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using `discord.js-selfbot-v13` and I've ran into a problem, the bot takes a list of channels that it needs to send a message to if X condition is true, however if the user gets banned from the guild it will throw an error saying message access.

Is there any way I can make it fetch the current available channels instead of the cached ones? when the user is banned the cached channels remain there for some reason so is it possible to re-fetch the cache to the latest version each time the loop happens?

I tried using `client.channels.cache.fetch(id)` and `client.channels.cache.get(id)`, both producing the same error of finding non-existent channels.

Here's the current code I'm working with:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if(watchlist.includes(message.channel.id)){
      let link = await filterLink(message.content)
      if(link != null){
         let updated = await updateLink(link)
         if(updated){
            sendList.forEach( async (id) => {
               try{
                  
               }catch(error){console.log(error)}
            })
         }
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured a way or a workaround which might be helpful for anyone having the same issue, which is to split the bot into two bots, one watches and then sends the data over to the other one using an express server here's the code for it

The first selfbot:

```
// update function
async function updateLink(link, channel) {
  if (link != null) {
    let target = getTarget(channel.id)
    if (target == null) {
      return false
    }
    let response = await axios.post(
      "handler link",
      {},
      {
        headers: {
          target: target,
          gamelink: link
        }
      }
    )
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}

// message event
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (watchlist.includes(message.channel.id)) {
    let link = await filterLink(message.content)
    if (link != null) {
      let updated = await updateLink(link, message.channel)
      if (updated) {
        console.log('\n['.cyan, '!'.brightMagenta, ']'.cyan, `Link successfully Updated!`.brightGreen)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The server & handler:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let Link = req.headers.gamelink
  let linksCopy = links
  linksCopy[req.headers.target] = Link
  links = linksCopy
  res.sendStatus(200)
  console.log('\n['.cyan, '!'.brightMagenta, ']'.cyan, `Starting message sending...`.brightGreen)
  client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('\n['.cyan, '!'.brightMagenta, ']'.cyan, `Successfully logged in!`.brightGreen)
  })
  client.login("token")
  sendList.forEach( async (id) => {
    try {
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(id)
      let lin = verifylinks(req.headers.target)
      if (channel) {
        channel.send(lin+"\n*Received from the selfbot!*")
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }) 
})

module.exports = router;
```

I hope this will be of help for anyone running with a similar issue!

Answer (score 1):

---

###### Warning: The usage of selfbots or automating a user account outside the scope of OAuth/APIs is against Discord's Terms of Service and can result in your account being banned.

---

Whilst you may be able to fetch cached channels using your personal account token to authenticate with discord.js, the functionality with Discord's API is significantly reduced and limited as a result of selfbotting and you do not have the same capabilities that bot tokens do such as [privileged gateway intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents), specifically the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent, which is required for what you're trying to do.

As a result, the channels you have access to within the cache would only ever be those that emit any events that your client is subscribed to receives updates for *(such as a user message)*. What you are trying to achieve is not functionally possible with selfbots.